# Dynamically save query results from OracleDataReader

Tags: vb.net, oracle, collections

VB.NET 2010
Framework 3.5

I'm querying a table where the schema is not static.  The number of fields can change from one day to the next.  Usually I create a class with properties for each field, loop through the OracleDataReader and populate a list of the class with values from the database. Disconnect from database, let the OracleDataReader go out of scope and have a nice list of objects representing the data from the query.

My problem is that this table's schema is dynamic. Other folks can create and drop fields in this table.  I need a way to query the table and 'save the results' in some sort of dynamic data structure, I prefer to use the vb.net list (of t) Class (System.Collections.Generic) as that's how I'm doing this in other parts of the app

Comment: So, just to understand, you're doing the equivalent of doing a `SELECT * FROM mytable` and want to store the schema in an object and the contents within a list of that object, but the schema can change on you from one day to the next?? You say you do this in other parts of your app... How do you do it there?

Comment: Yes its a SELECT * FROM Table . .  I just need to store the results of the query but I don't always know how many fields will come back

Comment: I can tell you how I did it once, but I'm DEFINITELY not saying it's the best way (hence posting it as a comment rather than a solution) - I created a `Dictionary(of String, MyObject)` with the key being the field name and the second being a small object storing the value datatype, etc... It sucked since you lose a lot of capabilities of knowing fields ahead of time, but it did serve a purpose. As another solution, I've often used straight DataTables to store the data directly, but it has the same limitations... Either way, hope someone here has a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a loop over all columns:

```
Dim dr as OracleDataReader

dr = ...
For i as Integer = 0 to dr.FieldCount -1 Loop
   Debug.Print("Column " & i & " is " & dr.Item(i).ToString)
Next
```

However, this code is not tested, I don't know if it works with `OracleDataReader`. Maybe you have to use `OracleDataAdapter` and `DataTable` instead:

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
Dim da as OracleDataAdapter

da = ...
da.Fill(dt)

For i as Integer = 0 to dt.Columns.Count - 1 Loop
   Debug.Print("Column " & i & " is " & dt.Columns(i).Caption)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of doing something like that is :

```
CREATE TABLE tmp1 AS SELECT * FROM perm_table
```

This will be the only way to survive a system crash/shutdown and be able to continue afterwards.
You'll also have to drop the table when you're done with it (implement tables GC)...

There are .net objects that can facilitate your content, if you want it to stay in memory - DataTable is the most used one for that.

and last thing - you can dynamically get the table structure from user_tab_columns, and fit your code to the specific column structure. you'll just have to use a generic object to represent the data, or to program your app to be able to handle nulls and versioning of the structures.

I recommend this approach - because with it you work hard once and do not need to even think about this issue in the future (and don't need to manage anything in the database...)